# Search from selected values of comboboxes windows forms C#

Tags: c#, search, combobox

I have like 10 combobox in a form and what i need to do is if a item from any combobox (may be 1 or more comboboxes) is selected, search if theres a coincidence in an string array and the value(s) selected from the combobox(es) but exclude the comboboxes that have not been selected or changed, I tried using if but its not enough or efficient way to do this I think, I was just wondering if theres any way to do this.

Comment: What does "if there's a coincidence in a string array" mean?  Also, it would help a lot if you posted the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to store the information on your class in a way that you can determine if the current `ComboBox` from the rest of the others.  I cam up with a small sample that tracks the changes that have been made to the `ComboBox` using an event handler on `SelectedIndexChanged` and used LINQ in order to filter out and exclude the current `ComboBox`.

```
List<ComboBox> _allComboBoxes;
ComboBox _comboBox1;
ComboBox _comboBox2;
string[] _values;

void InitForm()
{
    // TODO Implement values.
    _values = new string[0];
    _allComboBoxes = new List<ComboBox>();

    _comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
    _allComboBoxes.Add(_comboBox1);
    _comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged;

    _comboBox2 = new ComboBox();
    _allComboBoxes.Add(_comboBox2);
    _comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged;
}

void ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HasCoincidence(sender as ComboBox, _values, _allComboBoxes))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Coincidence occurred.");
    }
}

bool HasCoincidence(ComboBox comboBox, string[] values, IEnumerable<ComboBox> allComboBoxes)
{
    IEnumerable<ComboBox> excludedComboBoxes = allComboBoxes.Where(c => c != comboBox);

    throw new NotImplementedException("Implement ComboBox to string[] comparison.");
}
```